# jQuery UI Dialog Titlebar Issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-dialog, titlebar

I'm hoping that someone else has experienced this and can point me in the right direction as to the cause/fix.

The issue I am having is that I am using a jQuery UI-Dialog for some form input. When the dialog displays, it is devoid of the titlebar altogether. I cracked it open in firebug and noticed that there's a CSS item denoted as follows;

```
element.style {
  display:none;
}
```

The element.style, in Firefox appears to refer to /html/body/div[3]/div which is the div used for the titlebar itself. When I disable the display:none; the titlebar becomes visible. So, I know what is appearing to cause it, but it also appears that that css is the result of something happening possibly in jquery itself perhaps.

I originally thought that I might be having CSS conflicts due to my CSS files, so I commented them out and tried running the page with only the jquery libs and the custom css and images. Still get the same thing.

I have battling this for days now and could really use some advice.

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#dlgEditMlgData").dialog({ autoOpen: false, 
                                  modal: true, 
                                  show: 'blind', 
                                  hide: 'explode', 
                                  title: 'Mileage Entry Edit Utility'
    }); 
    $("#dlgEditMlgData").hide().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Are you setting title text (dom element title attribute or dialog options)?

Comment: I am setting the title text in the javascript that creates the dialog.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dlgEditMlgData").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  show: 'blind',
  hide: 'explode',
  title: 'Mileage Entry Edit Utility'
  });

  $("#dlgEditMlgData").hide().siblings().hide();
});

Comment: Do you have a link so we can see this in action?

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the offer to help. James and Mikael below both offered great advice that really helped clean this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#dlgEditMlgData").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'explode',
    title: 'Mileage Entry Edit Utility'
  }); 
  $("#dlgEditMlgData").hide().siblings().hide(); 
});
```

When you call .dialog the element is moved to the end of the document and inserted into a wrapper(The frame of the dialog).

But after that you call hide on the element and also hide its' siblings which means that you hide the div itself but you also hide the titlebar which is a sibling to the div after it has been moved. If you need to hide the siblings of the element try doing so before creating the dialog.

Comment: So, you're saying to call the hide siblings prior to the above code?

Comment: Before this line: $("#dlgEditMlgData").dialog({

Comment: Oh man! That was too easy! Thank you so very much for that answer. That was the problem. I moved it before the dialog definition block and also changed it so that it was hiding the container div and that worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you're calling $("#dlgEditMlgData").hide().siblings().hide()? When you initialize a  as a dialog with autoOpen set to false, the dialog is hidden to start. To show the dialog, you then call:

```
$('#dlgEditMlgData').dialog('open');
```

No need to explicitly call hide() on the dialog or its siblings.

Comment: I have multiple dialogs encapsulated within a container div so that each can be called on demand. If I don't hide siblings, the others will show on the page. Is there a better way to address this perhaps?

Comment: The other dialogs shouldn't show if they are all initialized with autoOpen: false. Could you update your example to show the problem caused by multiple dialogs?

Comment: James, thank you for the insight. I think that your answer and Mikael's were both right on the money. Thank you both! Problem solved. :)

Comment: I wish there was a way to check both of your answers as the valid one's used. Please forgive me that I gave Mikael the credit for this.

Comment: :( It says I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. I really apologize for this cuz your help was very well worth it also.

Comment: You need 15 rep to upvote. You're almost there. :) Have fun on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I do like how helpful people are here also. :)